# Notificaciones de celular inactivo

Tags: android

¿Qué librería o que método puedo usar para activar notificaciones cuando el celular esté suspendido?

Por ejemplo, un cronómetro que actúe en segundo plano y después de una cantidad determinada de tiempo notifique esa terminal.

Comment: Te referis a algo como esto? https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-push-notifications-on-android--cms-25870